# Visual Basic, Listbox, is it possible to check if an item gets unselected

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I want when the user using the program selects something in the list box, and then selects something else, between that action i want the program to do something, I hope it's clear what I mean.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to handle the `SelectedIndexChanged` event or the like and then remember the previous item yourself, e.g.

```vb
Dim previousSelectedIndex As Integer = -1

Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(...) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If previousSelectedIndex <> -1 Then
        'Use previousSelectedIndex here.
    End If

    previousSelectedIndex = ListBox1.SelectedIndex
End Sub
```

If you wanted to, you could create your own derived class inheriting `ListBox` and build that functionality into it.